# What is the use of project.properties file in android

Tags: android

When i first created android project , project.properties file has been generated.

It contains the information about target-platform and dependencies.

I deleted that file and tried to run my project , My Project runs without errors.

So,

1. what is the use of project.properties file.
2. It has been mentioned in the comment that "This file should be checked in "Version Control Systems". why ?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html):

**project.properties**

This file contains project settings, such as the build target. This file is integral to the project, so maintain it in a source revision control system. To edit project properties in Eclipse, right-click the project folder and select Properties.

I contains all the versions details of your application like minimum version,target version details , library details whichever you are adding in your project. Your applications target version etc. If you modify this file directly it will reflect to your overall project.

Comment: Is this file just for infomration about the project. It didnt affect the project from running when i deleted it and also it has not been regenerated again when i rebuild.

Comment: Yes it manages the project's version details the library details etc. It will be always auto-generated if you delete it and get the needful details of your project.

Comment: In My case, It is not regenerating again when i rebuild. I dont know why ? I am using Eclipse with ADT plugin.

Comment: Try to clean your project.